# SqlDataSource Based Dropdown list

Tags: c#, dynamic, sqldatasource, dropdownlistfor

I have created a dropdown list which fetched filtered data based on status.

But my already inserted data may have some entries that are not active at the moment.
Initially I applied a `DatasourceID` to a dropdownlist

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Country" runat="server" CssClass="roundDDL" 
                  DataSourceID="SDS_Country" 
                  DataTextField="Descr" DataValueField="Code">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Now on a click I want to change the `DatasourceId` as per new `SDS_Country_All`

```
DDL_Country.DataSourceID = "SDS_Country_All";
DDL_Country.DataValueField = "Code";
DDL_Country.DataTextField = "Descr";
```

I have also tried to apply `databound();` etc.

It is continuously giving me error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a SQL error.  Check the select statement for SDS_Country_All

Comment: thanks a lot. please help me in one more thing.. i want to create a tabulare form view.. and am unable to do so. i want user to insert as many records as he wishes. like the oracle developer  tabular form...

Comment: Look into asp:ListView and asp:GridView.  Which one is better is going to determine how you want it to look and what you want it to do.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790(v=vs.100).aspx